# str_extract expressions in R

Tags: r, regex, string, expression, stringr

I would like to convert this:

```
AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1
```

to this:

```
ELA-3
```

I tried this function:

```
str_extract(.,pattern = ":?(ELA).*(\\d\\-)"))
```

it printed this:

```
"ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-"
```

I need to get rid of the text or anything between the two extracts. The number will be a number between 3 and 9. How should I modify my expression in `pattern =`?
Thanks!

Comment: Your regex `:?(ELA).*(\d\-)` doesn't match anything in your target string. Perhaps you were mistaken when you said `it printed this "ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-"`

Comment: any suggestions to modify my expression to grab "ELA-3" from the text?

Comment: You can't do that with a single call to `str_extract` because you cannot match discontinuous portions of texts within a single match operation. Capturing groups only keep parts of text you match in separate memory buffers, but you also need a method or function that is capable of accessing these chunks. `str_extract` drops them, `str_match` keeps them.Try `m <- str_match(s, ":?(ELA).*-(\\d+)")` then `paste0(m[,2], "-", m[,3])` and you will get `ELA-3`.
`

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Match everything up to `-ELA` followed by anything (`.*`) up to `-` followed by captured digits (`\\d+)`followed by `-` followed by anything.  Then replace that with `ELA-` followed by the captured digits.  No packages are used.

```
x <- "AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1"
sub(".*-ELA.*-(\\d+)-.*", "ELA-\\1", x)
## [1] "ELA-3"
```

**2)** Another approach if there is only one numeric field is that we can read in the fields, grep out the numeric one and preface it with `ELA-` . No packages are used.

```
s <- scan(text = x, what = "", quiet = TRUE, sep = "-")
paste("ELA", grep("^\\d+$", s, value = TRUE), sep = "-")
## [1] "ELA-3"
```

Comment: I am trying to use str_extract() function. Does the meaning of expressions differ from sub() to str_extract()? ".*-ELA.*-(\\d+)-.*" did not print "ELA-3" in my case?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR;

You can't do that with a single call to `str_extract` because you **cannot match discontinuous portions of texts within a single match operation**.

Again, **it is impossible to match texts that are separated with other text into one group**.

## Work-arounds/Solutions

There are two solutions:

- *Capture parts of text you need and then join them* (2 operations: *`match`* + *`join`*)
- *Capture parts of text you need and then replace with [**backreferences**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the groups needed* (1 *`replace`* operation)

[**Capturing groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) only keep parts of text you match in separate memory buffers, but you also need a method or function that is capable of accessing these chunks.

Here, in R, `str_extract` drops them, but `str_match` keeps them in the result.

```
s <- "AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1"
m <- str_match(s, ":?(ELA).*-(\\d+)") 
paste0(m[,2], "-", m[,3])
```

This prints `ELA-3`. See [R demo online](https://rextester.com/RKXU27977).

Another way is to replace while capturing the parts you need to keep and then using backreferences to those parts in the replacement pattern:

```
x <- "AIR-GEN-SUM-UD-ELA-NH-COMBINED-3-SEG1"
sub("^.*-ELA.*?-([^-]+)-[^-]+$", "ELA-\\1", x)
```

See [this R demo](https://rextester.com/MGPYSG85173)